# Validar CNPJ países América Latina

Tags: regex

Estou fazendo uma uma validação de CNPJ dos países da América Latina.
Não entendo muito bem o `Regex` e gostaria de  ajuda para validar a seguinte regra:

> 3 digits, 6 numbers (YYMMDD), 3 digits (like P&G851223B24)

O campo tem que aceitar 3 dígitos + 6 números + 3 dígitos e estou fazendo com jquery assim:

```
 $('.cnpj-mask_3061').mask('AAA000000aaa', defOptions);
```

Obs: No México não deu certo.

Comment: Você precisa aplicar uma máscara ou validar a informação?

Comment: O método `mask()` não é apropriado para validação. É meramente para criar uma formatação, uma máscara.

Answer (score 2):

A máscara que você utilizou (`AAA000000aaa`) faz com que os 3 primeiros e últimos caracteres sejam apenas letras, e não alfanuméricos e símbolos também.

Uma aproximação da solução seria a expressão:

```
/^.{3,4}\d{6}.{3}$/
```

Onde `^.{3,4}` define que o valor deve começar com 3 ou 4 quaisquer caracteres, `\d{6}` define que em seguida serão 6 números e `.{3}$` define que o valor deve terminar com quaisquer 3 caracteres.

Exemplo funcionando no [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/direboluho/edit?html,js,output).

Como não encontrei nada além do [texto do Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAT_identification_number) sobre os formatos corretos não posso lhe garantir que esta validação está 100% correta, sugiro pesquisar mais sobre os formatos e também estudar sobre [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), pois nem todos os plugins e máscara para jQuery são tão flexíveis como se faz necessário no seu caso.